# How to add a tickbox if next cell is not blank (must be a function)

Tags: google-sheets

**Edit: My second script actually works, it just doesn't recognize a zero "0" as being data so it sees a blank instead.
After changing it from "B" to "C" which contains words instead of numbers the script works every time.**
Should I remove this question? @mods

I've created a script that will add a checkbox in A1 if B1 is not empty.
For some reason it only works on row 1 when I run it, and I want it to execute for the whole sheet from A2:A100.

I tried this first:

```
function addTickboxToColumnA() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange("A:B").getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][1] != "") {
      sheet.getRange('A' + (i + 1)).insertCheckboxes();
    }
  }
}
```

Then this

```
function addTickbox() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1:A'+lastRow);
  var values = range.getValues();

  for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    if(sheet.getRange('B'+(i+1)).getValue() != '') {
      sheet.getRange('A'+(i+1)).insertCheckboxes();
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help. I've searched and found a lot of answers that suggest using conditional formating to hide tickboxes, but this won't work for me as I use a lot of "getlastrow" so filling column a with hiden or white tickboxes is no bueno.